# Global.asax not firing on one application, only on my machine, only local

Tags: c#, asp.net

I support a dozen old C# and VB.NET applications, some artifacts from as far back as the early 2000's.  Some were created as aspx, some as asp and later converted.

There is one application which is C#, currently framework 4.5, run from VS 2013.  The problem I am having is that when I try to run it locally, it never fires any of the events in the global.asax.  Instead, just goes right into the Master file without setting the session variables that the global.asax should have set.  Breakpoints set in the Application_Start are never hit. However, when I publish it to our staging or productions environments, it functions normally.

Normally I might suspect something in the web.config file, but here is the oddest part of the thing; my teammates have no difficulty running it locally in debug mode.  It goes into their global.asax just fine.  We all work out of the same set of code stored in Subversion.

I have tried blowing away all code, bin, debug, everything in the application folder and reacquiring from Subversion source code, but the problem persists.  My team lead even gave me his .suo in case there was something weird in my setting when the suo was created.  Nada.

All of my other applications function as expected when running local and in debug.  Breakpoints set in global.asax are hit normally.

My markup is as follows: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="UAR.Global" Language="C#" %>

Nothing out of character, looks just like the global.asax for all my other apps.

I hate to have to completely reinstall my VS but that is the only thing I can think of at this point, and is what my team lead is suggesting.  It seems to be specific to my machine, only for this application and this mode of execution, and I can only hope it simply has something to do with some switch that got accidentally set on my VS.

Has anyone else run into this specific problem (and solved it), or do you have any idea what switch on VS might cause behavior like this?

Comment: Restart your IIS server. `Global.asax.cs` only fires when the site starts up (not on every request). Also, it can be the case that IIS starts up before your debugger attaches (and so the code executes without hitting a breakpoint).

Comment: Also any modification to your web.config will fire the reload of the web and it will fire the event.

Comment: I restarted IIS in my local machine, and I saved changes to my web.config.  Global.asax still not firing when I run this application.